# Comapring dates of two different formats in Groovy

Tags: date, grails, groovy

I am trying to find out which date is coming after the other date.
However, the initial string date values I have are of different formats.

Something like as mentioned below.

```
def date1 = "2021-02-22"

def date2 = "12/17/2019 11:55:00 PM UTC"
```

Can someone help me with how I can compare the above dates in my groovy code?

Comment: theres no other option than parsing the dates with `SimpleDateFormat` and comparing results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in Groovy:

```
Date date1Parsed = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', date1)
Date date2Parsed = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z', date2)
```

Then you can make calculations, e.g.

```
if (date1Parsed < date2Parsed)
```

If you want to convert them to formatted strings, do it like this (with whatever format you want):

```
date1Parsed.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSS Z")
```

For formatting options, you can start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can also look at Groovy's [TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) and [TimeDuration](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html) for more advanced options for date and time calculations.